# Excel input data following mouse trajectory away from intended cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Well past my three score and ten, and changes to excel seem to be overtaking me.
We don't really think what we are doing when inputting data quickly into a worksheet, but suddenly I find that when I scroll to the next cell the data intended for the previous cell follows the mouse to its new destination.
Too lazy to diagnose this peculiarity - so any suggestions welcomed.
Is there a "Reset Options to Default" facility in Excel (Microsoft 365 & Windows 10)

Long live CP/M, Supercalc & Leo Computers

Comment: Do you have custom mouse macros or other custom Excel button settings? Only word has the ability to reset the user option, excel does not have.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have very much to go on from your description—does "scroll", for example, refer to use of the mouse wheel, or a scroll-bar, or perhaps something else such as a trackpoint or trackpad.

But it's hard to imagine any kind of scrolling having the effect you describe.

Therefore I think you have a hardware problem.

For example, if it's the mouse wheel you're scrolling with, and the mouse has developed an intermittent defect, then it's quite possible the scrolling is triggering some click activity too. In that case the sum total of your mouse action plus random clicks could easily equate to drag-and-drop as far as Excel's concerned.

So I recommend you obtain another mouse.